# Correct Way to Scale Cassandra Cluster Using Authentication

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

Upon starting and adding a new node to my Cassandra cluster that is configured to use authentication, I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException: Cannot add already existing column family "credentials" to keyspace "system_auth"
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:242)
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.process(PasswordAuthenticator.java:266)
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.setupCredentialsTable(PasswordAuthenticator.java:214)
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.setup(PasswordAuthenticator.java:171)
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.Auth.setup(Auth.java:132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:830)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:583)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:482)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:345)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:462)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:552)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.AlreadyExistsException: Cannot add already existing column family "credentials" to keyspace "system_auth"
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewColumnFamily(MigrationManager.java:209)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.CreateTableStatement.announceMigration(CreateTableStatement.java:114)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SchemaAlteringStatement.execute(SchemaAlteringStatement.java:71)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:188)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:234)
        ... 10 more
```

This makes sense, as one of the prior nodes will already have created it.

What is the correct approach to bringing new nodes online, given that the `system_auth` column family already exists? Additionally, how does one cater for increasing the replication factor of the `system_auth` table as the size of the cluster increases?

Comment: This question is tagged as `cassandra-2.0` so if you look at the [relevant source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/2.0.0/org/apache/cassandra/auth/PasswordAuthenticator.java#208) it appears to be doing a check if the column family is missing (metadata == null) before trying to create it.  You may need to seek support from the Cassandra users list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't been able to find anything specific on that error it might well be a warning as you correctly state, it should already exist. I'm assuming that the node started and joined the cluster ok.

To answer your questions:

> What is the correct approach to bringing new nodes online, given that the system_auth column family already exists?
>
> Additionally, how does one cater for increasing the replication factor of the system_auth table as the size of the cluster increases?

I wasnt able to post more than one link on this answer, however searching the Datastax documentation for adding nodes will give you the general proceedure for adding nodes which will be the same wether using authentication or not,  the only difference being the authentication settings in the cassandra.yaml

Configuring the system_auth keyspace with replication is covered in the following documentation:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfSysAuthKeyspRepl.html